# How do I create a nested model while keeping the inner class private?

Tags: c#, api, oop, encapsulation, access-modifiers

I want to encapsulate Filter class within my FilterSelection model so Filter cant be instantiated on its own. However trying to set a property to access the list I get this error:

Inconsistent accessibility: property type is less accessible then property

```
public class FilterSelection
    {

        public List<Filter> List { get; set; }

        public FilterSelection()
        {
            List = new List<Filter>();
        }


        private class Filter
        {
            public string CustomFilterName { get; set; }
            public string workBook { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't expose a property to code that might use your class without also exposing the type of that property. In other words, if you are going to let my code create a FilterSelection and as such you are going to give me access to "List" (I would encourage a better name), if "List" is a collection of "Filter" objects, what use would they be to me if I know know what a "Filter" is? So, either class "Filter" needs to be public, or property "List" needs to be private. Alternatively, you could make both "internal" if you just want to use it within your FilterSelection class without exposing it.

Comment: Define a public interface and let your class inherit from it and declare your member of List<interface> - eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/1pSjrT

Comment: Mark the `List` property `private set;` Remember, adding and removing items from a list is still a `get` operation, even though you are making changes: you "get" the reference to the object, and then use the reference to call the object's "Add()" member function.

Answer (score 2):

The accessibility of the property and the type must be consistent (or at least, the property must have less than or equal accessibility to the type).

Option 1 - make the property and type available to any code which references your class:

```
public class FilterSelection
    {

        public List<Filter> List { get; set; }

        public FilterSelection()
        {
            List = new List<Filter>();
        }


        public class Filter
        {
            public string CustomFilterName { get; set; }
            public string workBook { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Option 2 - don't allow access to either the property or the class with the exception of in your class's constructor(s).

```
public class FilterSelection
    {

        private List<Filter> List { get; set; }

        public FilterSelection()
        {
            List = new List<Filter>();
        }


        private class Filter
        {
            public string CustomFilterName { get; set; }
            public string workBook { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Option 3 - Make the class and property available to any class within this assembly, but not outside of the assembly

```
public class FilterSelection
    {

        internal List<Filter> List { get; set; }

        public FilterSelection()
        {
            List = new List<Filter>();
        }


        internal class Filter
        {
            public string CustomFilterName { get; set; }
            public string workBook { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Option 4 - make your property and class available to your class and any class which inherits your class

```
public class FilterSelection
    {

        protected List<Filter> List { get; set; }

        public FilterSelection()
        {
            List = new List<Filter>();
        }


        protected class Filter
        {
            public string CustomFilterName { get; set; }
            public string workBook { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm currently working on a Web API and this is a DTO.  Having Filter set to public/internal would mean that Filter can be instantiated without FilterSelection. And setting it to protected/private would mean that I cant access my List property from the controller or service layer. I want my filter class to be coupled with FilterSelection and not to be used anywhere else if that is possible.